# Why is this SQL query running forever?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to find "Find the actors that were never unemployed for more than 3 years at a stretch".

Table schema is as follows

```
--------------------   -----------------------   ----------------------
|   Movie          |   |     Person           |  |       Cast         |
--------------------   ------------------------  ----------------------
| MovieID  | year  |   |  PersonID  | Gender  |  | MovieID | PersonID |
--------------------   ------------------------  ----------------------
```

I tried joining and doing sub queries. However my SQL statement is running forever on sqlite

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(A.PID), A.NAME FROM PERSON A 
WHERE TRIM(A.PID) NOT IN (

SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(B.PID) FROM M_CAST B, MOVIE C WHERE TRIM(B.MID) = 
TRIM(C.MID) AND EXISTS (

SELECT TRIM(D.MID) FROM M_CAST D, MOVIE E WHERE TRIM(D.MID) = TRIM(E.MID) 
AND TRIM(B.PID) = TRIM(D.PID) AND (CAST (SUBSTR(TRIM(E.YEAR), 
LENGTH(TRIM(E.YEAR)) -3 , 4) AS INT) - 3) >

CAST (SUBSTR(TRIM(C.YEAR), LENGTH(TRIM(C.YEAR)) -3 , 4) AS INT) AND NOT 
EXISTS (

SELECT TRIM(F.MID) FROM M_CAST F, MOVIE G WHERE TRIM(F.MID) = (G.MID) AND 
TRIM(B.PID) = TRIM(F.PID) AND 
CAST (SUBSTR(TRIM(C.YEAR), LENGTH(TRIM(C.YEAR)) -3 , 4) AS INT) < CAST 
(SUBSTR(TRIM(G.YEAR), LENGTH(TRIM(G.YEAR)) -3 , 4) AS INT) AND
CAST (SUBSTR(TRIM(G.YEAR), LENGTH(TRIM(G.YEAR)) -3 , 4) AS INT) < CAST 
(SUBSTR(TRIM(E.YEAR), LENGTH(TRIM(E.YEAR)) -3 , 4) AS INT)
)

)

)




CAST (SUBSTR(TRIM(C.YEAR), LENGTH(TRIM(C.YEAR)) -3 , 4) AS INT) #was used 
since the year had some special characters and was used to extract only the 
last 4 digits (year)
```

The expected result is to display all the name of the actors who were not unemployed for more than 3 years but my query is running forever with no results produced.

Comment: Add sample data and your expected output.

Comment: `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output would be useful too. You have a bunch of joins (using the archaic comma syntax instead of standard `JOIN` for some reason?) and I bet you don't have appropriate indexes on a lot of them. That hurts performance a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question.  It is much easier using window functions in the most recent versions of SQLite.

Here is one approach:

- Get a distinct list of all years that a person works.
- Use this list to find persons who have worked for three years in a row (that is a given year plus the next two).
- Select everyone who is not in this list.

You can stop here and work on the problem yourself.  As an editorial comment, this would be much simpler with window functions.  But only the most recent versions of SQLite support those.

The spoiler:

```
with py as (
      select distinct c.personid, m.year
      from cast c join
           movie m
           on c.movieid = m.movieid
     ),
     py3 as (
      select distinct py.personid
      from py join
           py py1
           on py1.personid = py.personid and
              py1.year = py.year + 1 join
           py py2
           on py2.personid = py.personid and
              py2.year = py.year + 2
     )
select p.*
from person p
where not exists (select 1
                  from py3
                  where py3.personid = p.personid
                 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=9373f6f71347e272a1278991b489f493) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that the code works.  (There is no data, just a demonstration that the code is correct.)

Comment: could you please elaborate on this? I have a very little knowledge regarding writing these kind of queries. It is throwing an error when I run? Please help me

Comment: @SanjeevRam . . . I have included a db<>fiddle to illustrate that the code works.  It does not generate an error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff .Can u help me with which window functions to be used in this scenario

Comment: @user3330998 . . . A new question should be asked as a *question*, not as a comment.